# How can I use the same widget twice in one page

Tags: php, yii2

I am using fotorama widget, and I want to create a comparison page.

I divide the page and use 2 widgets to compare images

I have tried to modify the source, but it still does not work

This is the source code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<center>
 <?php 
$fotorama = Fotorama::begin(
    [
        'options' => [
            'height' => '540px',
            'width' => '720px',
            'loop' => true,
            'hash' => true,
            'ratio' => 800/600,
            'transition' => 'dissolve',
            'arrows' => true,
            'nav' => 'thumbs',
            'navposition' => 'bottom',
            'thumbwidth' => 50, // Number. Tumbnail width in pixels.
            'thumbheight' => 50, 
        ],
        'spinner' => [
            'lines' => 20,
        ],
        'tagName' => 'span',
        'useHtmlData' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'custom-class',
            'id' => 'custom-id',
        ],
    ]
);
$id = Yii::$app->request->queryParams['id'];
switch ($id) {
     case '1':
         $folder = "gsmap7";
         break;
     case '2':
         $folder = "ismidx";
         break;     

     default:
         # code...
         break;
 } 

foreach ($dataProvider as $model ) {
    echo "<img src=\"../img/{$folder}/{$model->NAMA_FILE}\" > ";
}   

$fotorama->end(); ?>
</center>
</div><div class="col-sm-6">
<center>
 <?php 
$fotorama2 = Fotorama::begin(
    [
        'options' => [
            'height' => '540px',
            'width' => '720px',
            'loop' => true,
            'hash' => true,
            'ratio' => 800/600,
            'transition' => 'dissolve',
            'arrows' => false,
            'nav' => 'thumbs',
            'navposition' => 'bottom',
            'thumbwidth' => 50, // Number. Tumbnail width in pixels.
            'thumbheight' => 50, 
        ],
        'spinner' => [
            'lines' => 20,
        ],
        'tagName' => 'span',
        'useHtmlData' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => [
            'class' => 'custom-class',
            'id' => 'custom-id',
        ],
    ]
);

switch ($id) {
     case '1':
         $folder = "ismidx";
         break;
     case '2':
         $folder = "";
         break;     

     default:
         # code...
         break;
 } 

foreach ($dataProvider_compare as $model ) {
    echo "<img src=\"../img/{$folder}/{$model->NAMA_FILE}\" > ";
}   

$fotorama2->end(); ?>
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is what happened

[image]

Is it posibble to use same widget on one page or not?
Or can you tell me cool widget is showing image thumbnail and navigation next, prev , and play? It is like image viewer in the windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a different [`id`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#$id-details) for each widget. From your code above they have both been set to

```
'id' => 'custom-id',
```

Note that if you do not set id explicitly, it will be [automatically generated](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#getId%28%29-detail).

Comment: how? where i can find id => 'cutom-id'?